# Find the overall result using for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop

```
for i=1:30
randomno=rand(3,1); 
k(i)=mean(randomno(:,1) ;

end
```

How to stored the data of mean of k into result in workspace like:
Result=[mean value of k(1);mean value of k(2); till.....mean value of k(30)]